# How to implement the observer pattern for REST API's?

Tags: spring, rest, api, observer-pattern

I'm looking to create a REST API to which clients subscribe to certain data. When the data changes (due to some external event) I want to notify the clients (observers) with the new data.

I want to use Spring for the REST API's, I have no clue how to register and notify the observers though.

Some guidance and or good practises would be very helpful.

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

In spring boot you can register call back urls, an example controller is:

```
@RestController
public class Controller {

    private List<Listener> listeners = new ArrayList<>();

    @RequestMapping(value = "/register/{name}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<Void> register(@PathVariable("name") String name, @RequestParam("callbackurl") String callBackUrl) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("register, name=" + name + ", callBackUrl=" + callBackUrl);
        Listener listener = new Listener(name, URLDecoder.decode(callBackUrl, "UTF-8"));
        listeners.add(listener);
        System.out.println(listener);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/callback/*", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity callBack(@RequestBody String message) {
        System.out.println("call back with message=" + message);
        return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 10000)
    public void notifyListeners() {
        System.out.println("notifying listeners");
        for (Listener listener : listeners) {
            System.out.println("listener " + listener);
            CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(listener.getCallBackUrl());
            try {
                httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity("hello listener " + listener));
                CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);
                client.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can be tested like so, register 2 call backs, the URL http://127.0.0.1:8080/callback/app1 is encoded so it can be a paramter.

```
curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:8080/register/listener1?callbackurl=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A8080%2Fcallback%2Fapp1
curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:8080/register/listener1?callbackurl=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A8080%2Fcallback%2Fapp2
```

In my case for simplicity the client and server are the same application, but they could be different.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Spring 5 with WebFlux. It's a combination of an Iterator and the Observer pattern. The client always gets a new Object, whenever there is one on the server. You can start learning more on that on the Spring documentation pages or on e.g.
[New in Spring 5: Functional Web Framework](https://spring.io/blog/2016/09/22/new-in-spring-5-functional-web-framework)